# $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}[\log n]}$ versus $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}||}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I know that $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}[\log n]}$ (logarithmically many calls to the NP oracle) is equivalent to $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}||}$ (polynomial number of parallel queries to the NP oracle). I was wondering wether the "function" version of these classes are also equivalent, that is, whether

$$ \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}[\log n]} = \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}||}$$
If it is known to be true, a pointer would be really helpful.

Answer (score 16):

This is an open problem, it implies $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{RP}$ among other things. 
See the following paper:

Alan Selman. A Taxonomy of Complexity Classes of Functions. Journal of Computer and Systems Sciences 48 (1992), pp. 357-381.

You can get it here:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.32.7438&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: In that paper they use the class $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}}_{tt}$, can I assume that $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}}_{tt}=\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}\|}$? as a side question, is there a prototypical $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}\|}$-complete set?

Comment: On the side question: Do you mean complete sets for $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}||}$? The only natural one I know of is computing the winner in a Dodgson election, see the paper:
E. Hemaspaandra, L. Hemaspaandra and J. Rothe. Exact Analysis of Dodgson Elections: Lewis Carroll's 1876 Voting System is Hard for Parallel Access to NP. J.ACM 44 (1997), pp. 214-224

Comment: On the first question: I don't know, but $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}[\log n]} \subseteq \mathsf{FP}_{tt}^{\mathsf{NP}} \subseteq \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}||}$, therefore $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}[\log n]} = \mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}||}$ implies $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}[\log n]} = \mathsf{FP}_{tt}^{\mathsf{NP}}$.

Comment: Actually, what I am looking is a problem complete for $\mathsf{FP}^{\mathsf{NP}||}$, and I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @JanJohannsen Can you look at the related question https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52898/what-is-the-relation-between-these-two-complexity-classes-fl-logzplp-and. Also is $FP_{||}(ZPP)$ contained in $FP_{log}(ZPP)$?